# Problems uploading App to Apple's App Store using RoboVM

Tags: android, ios, libgdx, app-store-connect, robovm

I'm using Eclipse, libGDX 1.2.0 and RoboVM 0.0.14.

In the last couple of days I was trying to upload my app to the app store with no success.

To be completely honest, I don't really know what am I doing wrong, so I decided to attach the following resources and hope that someone here will be able to assist me with this issue.

Thanks.

**Below you will find :**

1. Application Loader error message.
2. build.gradle file.
3. App ID details (from developer.apple.com).
4. iOS Certificates (from developer.apple.com).
5. iOS Provisioning Profiles (from developer.apple.com).
6. App Information (from itunes connect).
7. Keychain Access files (on my mac).

**Application Loader error message:**

> **Error 1:** "The bundle identifier cannot be changed from the current
>   value, 'com.tzamots.nGame'. If you want to change your bundle identifier, you will need to create a new application in iTunses Connect."
>
> **Error 2:** " invalid Code Signing Entitlements. The entitlements in your
>   app bundle signature do not match the ones that are contained in the
>   provisioning profile. According to the provisioning profile, the
>   bundle contains a key value that is not allowed:
>   'J3P5A3B6AS.com.tzamots.noniGame.iOSLauncher' for key
>   'application-identifier' in 'Payload/iOSLaouncher.app/IOSLaouncher"

**build.gradle file in the iOS directory:**

```
 robovm {
 iosSignIdentity = "iPhone Distribution: Tzamots (J3P5A3B6AS)"
 iosProvisioningProfile = "nGame_Dis (J3P5A3B6AS.com.tzamots.nGame)"
 iosSkipSigning = false
 stdoutFifo = ""
 stderrFifo = ""
 }
```

**App ID details (from developer.apple.com)**

> **Name:** noniGame
>
> **Prefix:** J3P5A3B6AS
>
> **ID:** com.tzamots.nGame

**iOS Certificates (from developer.apple.com)**

**1.**

> **Name:** Tzamots
>
> **Type:** iOS Development

**2.**

> **Name:** Tzamots
>
> **Type:** iOS Distribution

**iOS Provisioning Profiles (from developer.apple.com)**

**1.**

> **Name:** iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.tzamots.nGame
>
> **Type:** Development
>
> **App ID** noniGame (com.tzamots.nGame)
>
> **Status:** Active (Managed by Xcode)

**2.**

> **Name:** nGame_Dev
>
> **Type:** Development
>
> **App ID** noniGame (com.tzamots.nGame)
>
> **Status:** Active

**3.**

> **Name:** nGame_Dis
>
> **Type:** Distribution
>
> **App ID** noniGame (com.tzamots.nGame)
>
> **Status:** Active

**App Information (from itunes connect)**

> **SKU:** 123456
>
> **Bundle ID:** com.tzamots.nGame

**Keychain Access files (on my mac)**

*1.*

> **Name:** iPhone Developer: Tzamots (W72YA5HF6K)

*2.*

> **Name:** iPhone Distribution: Tzamots (J3P5A3B6AS)

Answer (score 3):

So.. I finally solved it :)

I had to remove the code from the build.gradle in my iOS directory and replace it in my root directory under `project(":ios")` then I changed the `iosSignIdentity` to be equal to the name of the distribution certificate as shown on my Keychain Access and the `iosProvisioningProfile` to the name shown in iOS Provisioning Profiles on developer.apple.com.

for the second part of the solution (Error 1) I had to open the robovm.properties file under the iOS root and to change the `app.id` so it will be like the one I used on my Provisioning Profile

Comment: Trying to solve error 2 - not working for me. Were you building with Gradle? Changing build.gradle and building from eclipse robovm plugin does nothing whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

For a more complete snippet of how this looks, here goes!

(build.gradle in ios project)

```
robovm {
iosSignIdentity = "iPhone Distribution: HelloWorld"
iosProvisioningProfile = "MyGamesDistributionProfile"
iosSkipSigning = false
stdoutFifo = ""
stderrFifo = ""
```

}