# Can't submit my IPA through Application Loader

Tags: ios, libgdx, ipa, robovm

I've just finished my first game with libgdx and I'm now trying to publish it. I had no problem with the Play Store but it seems to be a little bit more complicated with the App Store.

My problem is that when I'm trying to send the IPA (generated throug gradle command: gradlew ios:createIPA) throug the Application Loader it shows those errors:

[image: Image of problems from app loader]

I've already checked all the certificate and everything seems to be OK. I've created a clean provisioning profile for distribution and downloaded it.

I've already refreshed my account through XCode and I can see my certificates in **Keychain Access** and my provisioning profiles in **Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles**

Thanks for your help !

EDIT:
All the errors except ERROR ITMS-9000 are now gone (my firewall was too strict)

Comment: Does your computer or network have firewall because it seems to be blocking the SSH connection.

Comment: logout from ituneConnect and login again. resubmit app

Comment: Thanks rckoenes, it seems that the all errors except the ITMS-9000 are gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the answer !

Regarding this post: [Problems uploading App to Apple's App Store using RoboVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25460154/problems-uploading-app-to-apples-app-store-using-robovm)
I realized that I needed to add this:

```
robovm {
        iosSignIdentity = "iPhone Distribution: XXX xxx (******)"
        iosSkipSigning = false
        stdoutFifo = ""
        stderrFifo = ""
    }
```

in my root build.gradle if I want to sign my ipa...